CSS code to center and adapt size of page is not working
I'm trying to change a part of my website, and I can't get it to work. I want to get the content of the page always centered, and at the same time adapt to browser size, page size, or device type.
I have other pages on my site which work fine, so it has to be something with this part of the code.
Is there something I have to change or to add in order to get this to work as I want it to?


/*new timeline*/
:root {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
    margin: 10% 0;
    padding: 1% 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 50%;
}

body {
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(170, 230, 189);
}

header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    row-gap: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

header h1 {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 1% 0;
    border-radius: 50% 20% / 10% 40%;
    color: green;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

header p {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.main-container {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.line {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    height:100%;
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 10%;
    transform: translateX(-5%);
    background-color: blue;
}

.line a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(55, 131, 65);
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: auto;
}

.card {
    font-size: .8rem;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left {
    position: relative;
    left: -10%;
    right: 10%;
}

.right {
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
}

.left::after,
.right::after {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: rgb(18, 113, 48);
    border-radius: 0px 10px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    z-index: -1;
}

.left::after {
    top: 80%;
    right: -80%;
}

.right::after {
    top: 80%;
    left: -80%;
}

.card h1 {
    padding: 80%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(18, 113, 48);
}

.card p {
    padding: 80%;
}

.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.left .thumbnail {
    left: 80%;
}

.right .thumbnail {
    right: 80%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:790px) {
    body {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0 10%x;
    }

    .main-container {
        width: auto;
    }

    .line {
        height: 80%;
    }

    .card {
        top: 80%;
        margin-bottom: 80%;
    }

    .left::after,
    .right::after {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .left {
        left: auto;
    }

    .right {
        left: auto;
    }

    .left .thumbnail {
        top: -80%;
        left: 80%;
    }

    .right .thumbnail {
        top: -80%;
        left: 80%;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>xxxxx.</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <META NAME="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="xxxxx" >
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- custom CSS-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu&amp;subset=cyrillic,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">-->
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family : 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
        }        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header_btm">
        <div class="h_left">
            <h1><img src="images/xxxxx.png" /></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="h_right">
            <br />
            <br />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="Empresa.html">Empresa</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="destaques.html">Destaques</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="marcas.html">Marcas</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contactos.html">Contactos</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="areacliente.html">Area de Cliente</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <script src="js/classie.js"></script> 
            <script src="js/uisearch.js"></script> 
            <script>
                new UISearch( document.getElementById( &amp;#39;sb-search&amp;#39; ) );                        
            </script> 
<!-- start smart_nav * -->
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="Empresa.html">Empresa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="marcas.html">marcas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="contactos.html">Contactos</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsive.menu.js"></script> 
<!-- end smart_nav * -->
        </div>
      <div class="soc_icons">
        <br />
        <br />
        <ul>
          <li>
            <!--a href="http://www.facebook.com/xxxx"><img src="images/icon4_h.png"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/xxxx"><img src="images/icon5_h.png"/></a-->
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- start header -->
    <div class="header_btm">
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<!-- start main -->
    <div class="main_bg">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="main">
                <div class="content">
<!-- start about -->




<section style="background-color: #F0F2F5;">
  <div class="container py-5">
    <div class="main-timeline-2">
      <div class="timeline-2 left-2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(135).webp" class="card-img-top"
            alt="Responsive image">
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <h4 class="fw-bold mb-4">Ut enim ad minim veniam</h4>
            <p class="text-muted mb-4"><i class="far fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i> 2017</p>
            <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
              incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
              ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-2 right-2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(129).webp" class="card-img-top"
            alt="Responsive image">
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <h4 class="fw-bold mb-4">Duis aute irure dolor</h4>
            <p class="text-muted mb-4"><i class="far fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i> 2016</p>
            <p class="mb-0">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
              doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
              architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit
              aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem
              sequi nesciunt.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-2 left-2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(131).webp" class="card-img-top"
            alt="Responsive image">
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <h4 class="fw-bold mb-4">Sed ut nihil unde omnis</h4>
            <p class="text-muted mb-4"><i class="far fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i> 2015</p>
            <p class="mb-0">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur,
              adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam
              aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis
              suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure
              reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui
              dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-2 right-2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(125).webp" class="card-img-top"
            alt="Responsive image">
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <h4 class="fw-bold mb-4"> Quis autem vel eum voluptate</h4>
            <p class="text-muted mb-4"><i class="far fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i> 2014</p>
            <p class="mb-0">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis
              praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint
              occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi,
              id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-2 left-2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(144).webp" class="card-img-top"
            alt="Responsive image">
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <h4 class="fw-bold mb-4">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
            <p class="text-muted mb-4"><i class="far fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i> 2013</p>
            <p class="mb-0">Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus
              saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum
              hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut
              perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

            <!-- end about -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="footer_bg">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/easyResponsiveTabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $(&amp;#39;#horizontalTab&amp;#39;).easyResponsiveTabs({
                        type: &amp;#39;default&amp;#39;, //Types: default, vertical, accordion     
                        width: &amp;#39;auto&amp;#39;, //auto or any width like 600px
                        fit: true   // 100% fit in a container
                });
        });

    </script> 
    <!--script-->
    <div class="footer_top">        
        <div align="left">                  
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/xxx"><img src="images/tube.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/tubeb.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/tube.png'" style="width:40px;height:35px;"align="left"/></a>    
            <a href="#"><img src="images/espacio.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/espacio.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/espacio.png'" style="width:4px;height:35px;""align="left"/></a>  
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/xxxxx/"><img src="images/insta.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/instab.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/insta.png'" style="width:40px;height:35px;""align="left"/></a>   
            <a href="#"><img src="images/espacio.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/espacio.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/espacio.png'" style="width:4px;height:35px;""align="left"/></a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx/"><img src="images/faceblue.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/faceblack.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/faceblue.png'" style="width:40px;height:35px;""align="left"/></a>       
        </div>      
        <div class="f_nav1">
            <ul>                
                <li><a href="index.html"></a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>-->
                <!--<li><a href="marcas.html">marcas</a></li>-->
                <li><a href="privacidade.html">xxxxx</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br></br>   
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<!--script--> 
</body>
</html>




You have an extra closing div above your <!-- start header --> comment. Does removing that fix the issue? Consider running your code through a validator (or use an IDE that supports proper indentation and error checking/syntax highlighting) like https://validator.w3.org/nu/ to check for syntax errors or other issues in your HTML.

The Snippet isn't much use: you're using relative links, which don't work out of the context of your site. But besides that, it's a lot of code; can you reduce it at all? I'm sure not all the content is needed to demonstrate the issue.

@DarrylNoakes the first code is the CSS part of the code that "manages" the part I want centered and adapting. on the second part of the code, all i want is the part that starts with ** to be centered and adapting size and device

@questionador Please note my question above.

@TylerH I saw it, yes, and thanks for the advice. I have lots and lots of small (and not so small) errors, and i'm going trhough them, but none is responsible for not aligning in center and not adapting size.

@questionador OK. Please fix all such syntax errors before posting the code to Stack Overflow.

@TylerH so, at this moment, the information I need is to know how can I define the the whole page content is centered, and adapting to screen sizes and browsers, how do I define this?

@questionador Review documentation such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_cookbook/Center_an_element and see SO questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-can-i-vertically-center-a-div-element-for-all-browsers-using-css and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-can-i-horizontally-center-an-element
